# Rendering a PDF file, and/or converting PDF to PNG, with anti-aliasing and transparent background

Tags: luatex, pdf, backgrounds, transparency, png

I am trying to convert a LuaLaTeX-generated PDF file to a PNG file with anti-aliasing and a transparent background (white text on a black background). I have also posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711066/converting-a-pdf-to-png-with-anti-aliasing-and-transparent-background) to see if there are means of doing so after having generated the PDF file. However, I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way of doing this in LuaLaTeX itself? That is, can I generate the PDF file directly with a transparent background such that it is, in turn, reflected in the converted PNG file along with anti-aliasing?

Any advice or tips on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: By default there is no background, so it is transparent.  So what did you do to change that?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, okay! So I specifically wanted to generate white text. So I included the following: `\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}` and `\color[rgb]{1,1,1}`. So should I just exclude `\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}` then? Although this just generates a purely white PNG file.

Comment: @niran90 If you don't set a page color than there is no background in the PDF. If your PDF to PNG converter interprets that as an implicit white background or as transparent depends on your converter and no longer on TeX.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Oh, right. I now understand. So is `\color[rgb]{1,1,1}` specific to the text color? As in, does it still result in white text and leave the background untouched?

Comment: @niran90 Yes, it is.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Okay, perfect. Thank you very much for your help! :)